# Index.blade.php could not find Routes to Posts.destroy

Tags: php, laravel-8

I was trying to link my posts.delete to my index.blade.php but I keep getting Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException

index.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="flex justify-center">
        <div class="w-8/12 bg-white p-6 rounded-lg">
            <form action="{{ route('posts') }}" method="post" class="mb-4">
                @csrf
                <div class="mb-4">
                    <label for="body" class="sr-only">Body</label>
                    <textarea name="body" id="body" cols="30" rows="4" class="by-gray-100 border-2
                    w-full p-4 rounded lg @error('body') border-red-500 @enderror" placeholder="Post something!"></textarea>
                    @error('body')
                        <div class="text-red-500 mt-3 text-sm">
                            {{$message}}
                        </div>
                    @enderror
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded
                    font-medium">Post</button>
                </div>
            </form>
            @if ($posts->count())
                @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <div class="mb-4">
                        <a href="" class="font-bold">{{ $post->user->username }}</a>
                        <span class="text-gray-600 text-sm">{{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</span>
                        <p class="mb-2">{{ $post->body }}</p>

                        <div class="flex items-center">
                            @if (!$post->likedBy(auth()->user()))
                                <form action="{{ route('posts.likes', $post) }}" method="post" class="mr-1">
                                    @csrf
                                    <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Like</button>
                                </form>
                            @else
                                <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy', $post) }}" method="delete" class="mr-1">
                                    @csrf
                                    @method('DELETE')
                                    <button type="submit" class="text-blue-500">Unlike</button>
                                </form>

                            @endif
                            <span>{{ $post->likes->count() }} {{ Str::plural('likes', $post->likes->count()) }}</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                @endforeach

                {{ $posts->links() }}

            @else
                There are no posts...
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>

@endsection
```

PostLikeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PostLikeController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth']);
    }

    public function store(Post $post, Request $request)
    //While trying to add $request here it gave back an Undefined variable '$request'.
    //But after adding Request $request to it, it worked...
    {
        if ($post->likedBy($request->user())){
            return response(null, 409);
        }
        $post->likes()->create([
            'user_id' => $request->user()->id,
        ]);

        return back();
    }

    public function destroy(Post $post, Request $request)
    {
        dd($post);
    }

}
```

web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostLikeController;
use App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    //return view('welcome');
});

// Route::get('/', function () {
//     return view('posts.index');
// });

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
})->name('home');

Route::get('/dashboard', [DashboardController::class, 'index'] )
->name('dashboard')
->middleware('auth');

Route::get('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'index'] )->name('register');
Route::post('/register', [RegisterController::class, 'store'] );

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'] )->name('login');
Route::post('/login', [LoginController::class, 'store'] );

Route::post('/logout', [LogoutController::class, 'store'] )->name('logout');

Route::get('/login', [LoginController::class, 'index'] )->name('login');

Route::get('/posts', [PostController::class, 'index'] )->name('posts');
Route::post('/posts', [PostController::class, 'store'] );

Route::post('/posts/{post}/likes', [PostLikeController::class, 'store'] )->name('posts.likes');
Route::delete('/posts/{post}/likes', [PostLikeController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.likes');
```

Like.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Like extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id'
    ];
}
```

I checked my routes:list and I found that it was there

+--------+----------+--------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                | Name        | Action
| Middleware |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                  | home        | Closure
| web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user           |             | Closure
| api        |
|        |          |                    |             |
| auth:api   |
|        | GET|HEAD | dashboard          | dashboard   | App\Http\Controllers\DashboardController@index     | web        |
|        |          |                    |             |
| auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | login              | login       | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@index    | web        |
|        |          |                    |             |
| guest      |
|        | POST     | login              |             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@store    | web        |
|        |          |                    |             |
| guest      |
|        | POST     | logout             | logout      | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LogoutController@store   | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | posts              | posts       | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@index          | web        |
|        | POST     | posts              |             | App\Http\Controllers\PostController@store          | web        |
|        | POST     | posts/{post}/likes | posts.likes | App\Http\Controllers\PostLikeController@store      | web        |
|        |          |                    |             |
| auth       |
|        | DELETE   | posts/{post}/likes | posts.likes | **App\Http\Controllers\PostLikeController@destroy**    | web        |
|        |          |                    |             |
| auth       |
|        | GET|HEAD | register           | register    | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@index | web        |
|        |          |                    |             |                                                    | guest      |
|        | POST     | register           |             | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@store | web        |
|        |          |                    |             |                                                    | guest      |
+--------+----------+--------------------+-------------+----------------------------------------------------+------------+

**N.B:** I was trying to make it destroy the Likes that has been created but it keeps giving
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [posts.destroy] not defined. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\posty\resources\views\posts\index.blade.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your post like `store` and `destroy` has the same name set, you haven't registered a route with the name `posts.destroy` or `posts.delete`. Update the name on your route to the correct name.

```php
Route::delete('/posts/{post}/likes', [PostLikeController::class, 'destroy'])->name('posts.destroy');
```